# VirtualBox rc=-1912

Tags: virtualbox

Когда пытаюсь запустить любую машину выдает ошибку:

> RTR3Init failed with rc=-1912 (rc=-1912)- The VirtualBox kernel modules do not match this version of VirtualBox. The installation of VirtualBox was apparently not successful. Executing
>   '/sbin/cvbox configure'
>   may correct this. Make sure that you do not mix the OSE version and the PUEL version of VirtualBox.

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.

uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64
```

OC:Debian 8

```
dpkg -l |grep virtualbox*
rc  virtualbox                             4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
ii  virtualbox-5.1                         5.1.0-108711~Debian~jessie           amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
rc  virtualbox-qt                          4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
ii  virtualbox-source                      4.3.36-dfsg-1+deb8u1                 all          x86 virtualization solution - kernel module source
```

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250573/virtualbox-kernel-modules-do-not-match-the-version-of-virtualbox) (очень похож вопрос)

Answer (score 1):

Да, я тоже наткнулся на такие грабли c virtualbox-5.1.6.
Не помогло:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 'virtualbox*'
```

это то же:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
```

Никакие чистки стандартные запуски и прочее. Только ручками к сожалению.
У меня:

```
Debian Jessie-backports
4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1~bpo8+1 (2016-08-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Необходимо в каталоге

```
 /lib/modules/4.6.0-0.bpo.1-amd64/updates/dkms
```

Удалить все файлы модулей от предыдущей установки (по дате будет понятно)

```
vboxdrv.ko  vboxnetadp.ko  vboxnetflt.ko  vboxpci.ko
```

После этого переустановить virtualbox. (Не знаю нужно или нет, но dkms уже стоял)

Answer (score 1):

Тоже была такая проблема, что только не делал, на новой версии virtualbox 5.1, ни в какую не запускались виртуальные машины, тоже выскакивала такая ошибка. Приведенная в постах выше инфа тоже не спасла.

**Помогла команда:**

```
sudo apt purge virtualbox
```

Полностью удалилась версия 5.0.4, а версия 5.1 осталась и заработала. Хотя до этого удалял старую версию командой  `sudo apt remove virtualbox`, потом ставил новую версию. Но видать старая не до конца удалилась.

Версия ОС Linux Mint 18.1 Serena.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что virtualbox-dkms установлен:

```
dpkg -l | grep virtualbox-dkms
```

Если установлен - удалите его и установите dkms

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms && \
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Пересоберите VirtualBox kernel modules

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo rmmod vboxpci

sudo rmmod vboxnetadp

sudo rmmod vboxnetflt

sudo rmmod vboxdrv

sudo vboxconfig

"vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules."
"vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services."

sudo VirtualBox
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.